# Is there any method to make visual studio auto complete std::?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clion

Just like clion. For example, I want to use `std::vector<>`. In clion, I just need to input `vec` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Clion will autocomplete to `std::vector<>`. I think it is very convenient.  Is there any method to achieve this effect in Visual Studio?

effect:

[image]

Comment: It works as it should. If you don't have `using namespace std;` it's pretty normal that `ve..` won't be autocompleted. OTOH if you type `std::ve` it does autocomplete. It looks like a clever Clion feature to me that is not available in VS.

Comment: Clion doesn't convert `vec` to `std::vector<>` for me, typing `vec` and hitting enter gives just `vector`.

Comment: @ixSci what happens in Clion if you omit `using namespace std;`? I don't have Clion, so I can't check myself.

Comment: JetBrains (CLion producer) delivers also ReSharper - a plugin for VisualStudio! So with this plugin it should work. Plugin has many flavors and supports many languages not only C/C++.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I didn't have `using` when typed it. Also with Resharper++ there is zero reaction to `vec`.

Comment: Ok, it actually gives `std::vector` in some circumistances. It gave me just `vector` when I had  `using namespace std::string_literals;` in the file which looks like a bug to me. If I didn't have that line then it would be `std::vector` in CLion,

Comment: @ixSci No. At least at windows 10,  Clion can autocomplete std::  without any "using namespace". I  will upload a pic to show that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-cpp-code-snippets